# How to use Redux Toolkit createListenerMiddleware with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

## Problem

I am using Redux Toolkit and TypeScript to create a Todos app. I want to create middleware that will listen for a dispatched action so I can then dispatch async actions.

## What I have so far

```
// listenerMiddleware.ts
import { createListenerMiddleware, addListener } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { TypedStartListening, TypedAddListener } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

export type AppStartListening = TypedStartListening<RootState, AppDispatch>

export const startAppListening =
  listenerMiddleware.startListening as AppStartListening

export const addAppListener = addListener as TypedAddListener<
  RootState,
  AppDispatch
>

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todos: todosReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(listenerMiddleware.middleware),
})
```

## Question

How do I use the `startAppListening` and `addAppListener` objects to listen for a specific action? I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We do show extensive examples in the API reference page :)

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware

Generally, it's going to look like this:

```js
import { todoAdded } from "../features/todos/todoSlice"

startAppListening({
  actionCreator: todoAdded,
  effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
    // whatever logic you want here
  }
})
```

Comment: I couldn’t find an example of a listenerApi. Do you have one?

Comment: `listenerApi` is the second parameter that will be given to your effect callback function.  It includes methods like `dispatch` and `getState`, and also other async primitive functions like `take`, `condition`, and `delay.  You can see the list of all the methods that it includes here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#listener-api

Comment: Was looking for a way to get getState() typed correctly from listeners, and landed here. Very useful, thanks.

Is there something similar for RTK Query?

Comment: I think we answered that question over in our issues, but no. Due to technical differences, the best option for using `getState` inside of RTKQ is `baseQueryApi.getState() as RootState`.

Comment: Agree with @markerikson, it's probably not the best way but I can't find any other info on that topic atm